# Getting scale and translation difference to animate transition from a view to another?

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to make an animation set with a translate animation and a scale animation, to make a view move from it's size/position, to another view size/position.

I tried to get the positions with getX/getY or getLocationOnScreen to feed the translate animator, but no luck for the first view to match the second at the end of the animation :/

(same for scale animation)

Any idea ?

Comment: I'm almost there, but somehow, the translation affects the pivot from the scale, making the view a little "offsetted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it ... my problem was that I was applying translate animation first, and it was messing with pivot point for the scale animation.

The code sample below only translates on X.

```
View viewFrom = findViewById(R.id.viewA);
View viewTo = findViewById(R.id.viewB);
// Getting delta from center
int delta = (viewTo.getLeft()+Math.round(viewTo.getWidth()*viewTo.getScaleX()))-(viewFrom.getLeft()+Math.round(viewFrom.getWidth()+viewFrom.getScaleX()));
float ratio = viewTo.getScaleX() / viewFrom.getScaleX();
Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1.f, ratio, 1.f, ratio, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
animSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animSet.addAnimation(anim);
anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, delta, 0, 0);
animSet.addAnimation(anim);
animSet.setDuration(500);
viewFrom.startAnimation(animSet);
```